# How to embed font file in OpenXML Word document

Tags: c#, fonts, openxml-sdk

I'm building a Word document in OpenXML with C#.

One of the fonts I must use is a custom-made branded font. This font will not be available on customer machines.

Is it possible to embed font-file within **.docx** file and reference that font in font styles. If yes, how can this be done within C# SDK?

So far that does not seem to be possible, but I might have missed the documentation page somewhere.

p.s. I already have PDF with embedded fonts. Now I need the same looking Word document.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @jannikb Nope, not possible

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like what you need is a **.pdf**. So unless it absolutely must be a **.docx** I think that's your best option.

Help on generating a **.pdf** in C# can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630708/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-pdf-from-c).

Comment: I already have PDF. Now client wants the same looking document in Word.